# Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

There is the following model:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business

  has_attached_file    :image, styles: { medium: "640x260>" }
  validates_attachment :image, content_type: { :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ }
end
```

Also I've installed 'imagemagick' using brew (I use Mac OS). But when I was trying to execute the following code

```
@picture = business.pictures.build(picture_params)
@picture.save

def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:image)
end
```

I got the following error: `An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>`

I was trying to update PNG file:

```
= form_for [:admin, business, @picture] do |f|
    .row
        = f.file_field :image
        = f.submit 'Add'
```

How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I resolved this by reinstalling the imagemagick.

```
brew uninstall imagemagick jpeg libtiff
brew install imagemagick
```

Link freetype before installing imagemagick if it is not linked

```
brew link freetype
```

Comment: Any suggestions for windows users ??

Answer (score 0):

verify imagemagick using `identify`
 you should get something like this:-

```
milind@ubuntu:~/workspace/latest$ identify
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP   ....
```

and add this to `development.rb(`***knowing your path where imagemagick is installed***)

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/identify"
```