# Rails paperclip upload csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, paperclip

I want to upload `csv` file with `paperclip`

but i have got `Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError`

my form

`<%= form_for Upload.new do |form| %>
        <%= form.file_field :file %>
        <%= form.submit%>
<% end %>`

model

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },
      :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style_:filename"
  validates_attachment_content_type :file,  content_type: ['text/plain', 'text/csv', 'application/vnd.ms-excel'], message: "is not in CSV format"

end
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095396/papercliperrorsnotidentifiedbyimagemagickerror-in-rails-4)

Comment: @user8338151 You got fix for this?